# Removing similar items from linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I've noticed that after creating it's first Duplicate check and next both point to the same Mammal so when I then call great_circle which works out the distance between the two i get a list of 0's because it's comparing the same Mammal.

```
void remove_duplicates() {
int i,j;
double distance;
Mammal *next=head2.pointer;
for(i=0;i<list_length2-1;i++) {
    Mammal *check=next->pointer;
    Duplicate *d=malloc(sizeof(Duplicate));
    d->mampointer=NULL;
    d->number_of=0;
    for(j=0;j<(list_length2-i)-1;j++) {
        distance=great_circle(next->location, check->location);
        if(distance<=0.02 && next->species==check->species) {
            Mammal *a=next;
            Mammal *b=check;
            a->pointer=d->mampointer;
            d->mampointer=a;
            b->pointer=d->mampointer;
            d->mampointer=b;
            d->number_of++;
            d->number_of++;
        }
        printf("%f\n",distance);
        if (check->pointer!=NULL) {
            check=check->pointer;
        } 
    }
    if(d->mampointer!=NULL) {
        add_duplicate(create_duplicate(d));
    }
    if (next->pointer!=NULL) {
        next=next->pointer;
    } 
}
}
```

It seems that check is pointing to the same memory as next which should never happen, check should always be after next.

EDIT: The problem I'm trying to solve is:

There are several mammals with latitude and longitude co-ordinates,

Some of the mammals have been reported several times, but with slightly different co-ordinates,

I have to find these duplicates, and replace them with a single mammal with the average of the 'wrong' co-ords.

Comment: Q: what is your algorithm to "delete a duplicate"?  Could you explain what the code is supposed to do?  Q: What is "great_circle()"?  Q: Why do you "add_duplicate()" inside of "remove_duplicates()"?  Q: What exactly is the problem you're trying to resolve?

Comment: See edit for more info

Comment: It would help if you could really clean up your code. `check->pointer` shouldn't your nomenclature be `check->next` and instead of `Mammal *next` should be `Mammal *mPointer`. I would also advise for more formatting here `if(distance<=0.02 && next->species==check->species)` should be `if ((distance<=0.02) && (next->species == check->species))` its a way of short circuiting the statment.

Comment: What is `Mammal` ? What is `Duplicate `? What is `add_duplicate` ? What is `create_duplicate`? What is `head2` ? What is `list_length2` ? BTW that code looks as if it needed some serious refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link: http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/2252274/
That will help you traverse your linked list without redundant (and confusing) pointers like `head2` etc.

At first look it appears Kozmik's comment is correct about `check->pointer` should be `check->next` - but again, try to avoid redundant pointers unless it's making the code readable.

I find a graceful way to traverse a linked list is to stop when `cur_node->next == NULL` rather than allowing 'empty' nodes and having to check if `cur_node->next->item == NULL` (I'm assuming that `cur_node->pointer` is refering to the item you are storing in that node).

For example:

```
typedef struct node_s {
  void * item; // the item you are storing in this node
  node_s * next; // the next node
} Node;
typedef struct list_s {
  void * head;
  /* maybe some extra info like size etc */
} List;
```

Then traversing is easy:

```
List * list = malloc(sizeof *list);
list->head = NULL;

/* 
   create your first node etc, add to list in the obvious way.
   ...
   add more nodes
   ...
*/

//traversal
Node ** head = &list->head;
while (*head) { //we have a non-null node so keep going...
  Node *cur_node = *head;
  head = &cur_node->next;
  /* do stuff with current node (even delete it!). */
}
```

This way it's very simple, only two pointers to worry about (`head` and `cur_node`).